# how to use if else in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

How to perform following operation in knockout

```
      <div id="mainlist" data-bind="foreach: PageData.messages">
            <article class="comment_chain" id="_parentpost" >
            <div class="post_holder">

            <!-- ko if: ObjectId === 4 -->
            DO SOMETHING
           <!-- /ko -->
      </div>
```

here if condetion is no getting called properly . wat may b the reason for this.

Comment: Something wrong with your keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ObjectId an observable?  If so when you use an observable in an expression you have to remember that it is really a function and you need to use the () form to get the underlying value. Try this:

```
<!-- ko if: ObjectId() === 4 -->
```